# convert cURL get with username:password to angular get

Tags: php, angularjs, http, curl, get

I'm trying to use an API that wants an username and password in the request, they give an example in cURL like so:

```
  curl \
--user username:password \
--get \
--data-urlencode 'country=NL' \
--data-urlencode 'term=Groesman' \
'https://inquiry.creditandcollection.nl/api/companies'
```

Now I've tried this in angularJS:

```
    var auth = btoa(username + ':' + password);

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://inquiry.creditandcollection.nl/api/companies',
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Basic ' + auth
        },
        data: {
            'term': $scope.companyName
        }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

but still got a 401 back.

any help appreciated.

EDIT: this is not a dupe. I used btoa like in the other questions yes, but it's not working for me and I'm asking why

Comment: Have you made sure that the service supports the `Basic` authentication scheme? curl also supports other schemes, probably that's why the curl example works

Comment: It says "All requests require HTTP Basic Authentication". So I guess so yeah.